# Exactly when does a component update itself?

Tags: reactjs, redux

As far as I know, when a new `prop` is received, a component is updated based on `shouldComponentUpdate` function. I have the following container:

I am using redux, and I have the following inside my `container`.

```
function filterQuestions(allQuestions, answeredQuestions) {
  var filtered = _.reject(allQuestions, (q) => _.contains(answeredQuestions, q.question.id))
  return [...filtered]
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
  return {
    questions: filterQuestions(state.questions.questions, state.questions.answeredQuestions),
  }
}
```

My intention is that the connected `component` only updates when the output of `filterQuestions(...)` changes. However, the component updates everytime when there's a change in the global `store`. If I get rid of `filterQuestions` and simply pass `state.questions`, it shows the expected behavior.

I assume there's something wrong with the usage of `filterQuestions` but I am not sure exactly what is the issue. Can someone pinpoint it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Redux package does a shallow equality check whenever it calls your `mapStateToProps` function, comparing the current returned object against the previous returned object.  If the two objects' contents are shallow equal, it doesn't actually re-render your "real" component.

Whenever you use array functions like `map()` or `filter()`, you're returning a new array reference.  Even if the two arrays have the exact same contents, the objects that have those arrays as fields will no longer be shallow equal, and so React Redux will re-render your component.

There's two main ways to handle this:  either use memoized selector functions (such as those provided by the [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) package) so that you only re-run the filtering when the inputs have actually changed, or implement `shouldComponentUpdate` on your real component and implement smarter / more complex comparison logic, such as using `_.isEqual()`.

The Redux FAQ also covers this topic: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-rendering-too-often